# Is there a way to move around an enemy without acrobatics and attacks of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, opportunity-attack

I'm currently running Carrion Crown for my friends, one of whom knows the rules much better than I do. During one combat he used a full round action to move behind the enemy, through 3 separate threatened squares. He called it a "reposition" action; given his extensive knowledge, I just rolled with it and moved on with combat. I was thinking about it later and was curious so I went to look up the specific rules for it, but have come up blank.

Was I just deceived, or are my searching skills just sub-par?

Links or full notated rules appreciated.

Comment: Did your friend roll any dice to have his PC move in such a way, or did your friend just say *Gnargg the barbarian repositions himself here* or something?

Comment: ...Have you tried asking your friend to point out the rule in a rulebook so you can learn about it yourself?

Comment: It was done in such a way that I just assumed he knew what he was talking about. And I haven't had a chance to ask him about it personally, I'm probably just going to let it slide this time, but if it happens against I'll ask for a rule book.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe he used the [Withdraw Action](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Withdraw). As a full-action, you can move up to double your speed and the first square of movement is not considered as threaten, and *"despite the name, you don't actually have to leave the combat entirely"*.

With this, the barbarian may have moved back one square, move around his enemy while out of reach, and then reengaged him from an other angle (and called the maneuver "Repositioning of a fearless Barbarian" rather that "Withdrawal" ^^). If the player didn't describe the action completely, it may seem that the barbarian just moved on three (threaten) squares next to the enemy.

What he meant:

```
┌───<───┐
|       |
└>B E B─┘
```

What you saw:

```
┌─<─┐ 
B E B
```

That said, it would require that the enemy doesn't have *Reach*, and that there is actual room for that movement (remember that he can move through squares occupied by allies).

Answer (score 1):

There is a Reposition combat maneuver from the Advanced Player's Guide:

https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Reposition

But that is to do with moving your enemy. Perhaps that's what happened and he explained it poorly? If not, sounds like he's trying it on.